# Can you create a mapped type that maps keys to values?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a collection of functions like this:

```
const myFuncs = {
  appendFoo: (s: string) => `${s}FOO`,
  addFive: (n: number) => n + 5,
}
```

Mapped types let me do neat things like create a generic type for a collection of arguments mapped to one or more functions in `myActions`, like this:

```
type MyFuncInputs = Partial<{ [k in keyof typeof myFuncs]: Parameters<typeof myFuncs[k]>[0] }>
```

...but this makes the structure of the object I can describe with that generic type rather rigid. Suppose for example that `myFuncs` is a collection of handlers for a reducer, and I want to create a generic type describing an action for that reducer.

The following isn't valid typescript, but hopefully it will illustrate what I'd like to do:

```
type MyAction = {
  type: [k in keyof typeof myFuncs],
  payload: Parameters<typeof myFuncs[k]>[0]
}
```

Is there any way to create something like this?

The closest I've gotten is this, but I'd love a way to infer the value of `F` from the object's `type` instead of having to specify it twice:

```
type MyAction<F extends keyof typeof myFuncs> = {
  type: F,
  payload: Parameters<typeof myFuncs[F]>[0] 
}

const fooAction: MyAction<'appendFoo'> = {
  type: 'appendFoo',
  payload: 'bar'
}

const addAction: MyAction<'addFive'> = {
  type: 'addFive',
  payload: 1
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help!!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqxxjN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a way to ensure that the 'type' property and the 'payload' property type of your action are compatible with one of the functions in your myFuncs object. One way to do this would be to use union types and mapped types.

For example:

```js
type MyAction = { [K in keyof typeof myFuncs]: { type: K, payload: Parameters<typeof myFuncs[K]>[0] } }[keyof typeof myFuncs];

const fooAction: MyAction = {
  type: 'appendFoo',
  payload: 'bar'
}

const addAction: MyAction = {
  type: 'addFive',
  payload: 1
}
```

That is, we are generating a mapped type where each K key of myFuncs maps to a corresponding object with 'type' and 'payload' properties, transforming the mapped type into a union type where an object can be any of the objects defined in the mapped type.

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Comment: Actually I'm still having a problem I hope maybe you can help me with. 

This works until I try to write my reducer, which is something like this (simplified for clarity):

`const myReducer = (action: MyAction) => myFuncs?.[action.type](action.payload)`

ts complains that `string | number` is not assignable to `never`. When I tried this approach with my more complicated real-world code I got a similar complaint, only instead of `never` it complains `returnType1 | returnType2` cannot be assigned to `returnType1 & returnType2`. Any idea what's going on? Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, maybe the issue you're encountering it's because TypeScript's inability to make a direct correlation between the action.type and action.payload inside the myReducer function. I think that a typeguard will do the deal. I did an example: https://snippet.host/mxptxg